# Partial content 206 requests on nginx behind WebAuth

Tags: nginx, http-headers, single-sign-on, html5

I'm having a troubleshooting an issue that I think is likely due to WebAuth authentication when serving .webm videos.

The server I have is nginx 1.6.2. I can make 200 GET requests just fine. I also have two parallel configurations - TLS 1.2 (open) and "BasicAuth" TLS 1.2. By modifying the .htaccess for the folder, I can switch the same content between these configurations. The only configuration I am having trouble making these HTTP partials on is the WebAuth configuration.

I've tried to use tools like HTTP Live Headers to diagnose issue. As far as I can tell, these requests are simply not being made by the browser.

Has anyone run into something similar? Can anyone make any recommendations for the next steps or any ideas for troubleshooting?